# English equivalent for new Brazilian Portuguese slang term “desaplaudido”?

Tags: single-word-requests, colloquialisms, portuguese

I read [in Twitter](https://twitter.com/TCAvendano/status/1004704217012072449) <sub>in Spanish, translation mine</sub>:

> In Portuguese from Brazil there is a word for those people who always try to get attention but cannot achieve that because, in fact, they are not good at anything: he/she is a *desaplaudido*. It is wonderful. We have to import it to Spanish.

I was curious about it and dug around a bit, to find [WordReference does not recognize it](http://www.wordreference.com/ptes/desaplaudido) and also some people in that Twitter thread are replying to say they do not know the word. It must be some new, informal term.

Does English have a similar term for that?

Comment: I'm a Brazilian-born, native speaker, fluent and proficient in Brazilian Portuguese. I have never, ever heard the wird "desaplaudido". Not even once. I think it's either a regionalism, or a slang pertaining to a certain demographic.

Comment: A google search for "aplaudido" (*applauded*) yields 2.17 million results. Whereas for "desaplaudido" it returns only 3 thousand results, and the first pages are mostly for dictionaries and thesaurus. Excluding those, most results seems to be from tv and youtuber fandoms, sub celebrities gossip news and the like.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy interesting! It's gor for that I was saying that it might be quite specific. However, it was noted by the editor of El País in Brazil. In any case, I am curious about this definition having a term in English.

Comment: While the dictionary definition does not support it, the idiomatic way we use the word buffoon may come close https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buffoon  I believe we use it less for 'clown' as in funny but more as a person who we laugh at , not laugh with .

Comment: In case it's not obvious for all readers, the word is a juxtaposition of two very broadly used terms: the prefix "des" (here meaning "un-" or "non-") and "aplaudido" (applauded).

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy If you follow fedorqui’s original Twitter link, the first commenter mentions (in Spanish) how *desaplaudido* is a new bit of slang out of São Paulo, which may explain why you've not heard it yet. Following that are others commenting variously in Spanish and in Portuguese how they haven’t heard it either, not even *os paulistanos*. It must be rather new, but it does seem delightful.

Comment: Not a direct translation given the analyses above, but a _desaplaudido_ sounds like a _wannabe_ to me.

Comment: I think that _desaplaudido_ is a marvellous word. I shall start using it immediately and do my best to bring it into English as a transliteration. 'You, sir, are a desaplaudido ! and you are voted out of the club, forthwith.' (up-voted +1).

Comment: @NigelJ “The usual storm was raging in the House. As usual, many of the Majority and the most of the Minority were standing up—to have a better chance to exchange epithets and make other noises. Into this storm Count Falkenhayn entered, with his paper in his hand; and at once there was a rush to get near him and hear him read his motion. In a moment he was walled in by listeners. The several clauses of his motion were loudly applauded by these allies, and as loudly disapplauded—if I may invent a word—by such of the Opposition as could hear his voice.” Mark Twain, *Stirring Times in Austria*

Comment: @tchrist So, I shall be following a man who timed his punctuations (or so he claims) by how often he took a breath, how often he spit and how often he stopped for coffee. Not quite sure which bodily part one actually _disapplauds_ with. The House of Commons might well tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct English translation, but since it's such a new word in Brazilian Portuguese slang, perhaps we'll see a similar slang word emerge in English!

I agree with the suggestion made by @Tom22 that **buffoon** is probably one of the closest English words that describes something similar, although it's not nearly as descriptive as *desaplaudido*.

Answer (score 2):

We have the noun **try hard**

> A person who puts a large amount of effort into achieving a certain image, or counter-image, to the point where it is obviously contrived. Rather than achieving an image through genuine personality, the try-hard consciously attempts to fit a certain style through deliberate imitation, forced style, or scripted behavior. That is to say, he/she is trying hard to create an image.
>
> Examples:
>    An affluent, suburban dweller who makes great efforts to
>   cover himself in tattoos and piercings; try-hard.
>
> A person who wears certain items of clothing for the express intention
>   of appearing "non-conformist", and flaunts it; try-hard.
>
> Someone who purchases a motorcycle only to appear as a "bad-boy";
>   try-hard.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=try-hard